# Can blackouts affect my Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

So I got an Xbox 360 as a gift from my parents. My uncle told us that his Xbox broke when a sudden blackout happened while he was playing. So this got me curious, is what my uncle saying true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can affect the power source, yes. The most likely cause is a power surge that can affect electrical equipment and damage electrical systems, such as power supply, or the Xbox itself.

From [wikipedia on power outages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_outage)

> Computer systems and other electronic devices containing logic circuitry are **susceptible to data loss or hardware damage** that can be caused by the sudden loss of power. These can include data networking equipment, video projectors, alarm systems as well as computers. To protect against this, the use of an uninterruptible power supply or UPS can provide a constant flow of electricity if a primary power supply becomes unavailable for a short period of time. To protect against **surges** (events where voltages increase for a few seconds), which **can damage hardware when power is restored**, a special device called a surge protector that absorbs the excess voltage can be used.

As the excerpt states, a Power-Surge protection power board can help avoid this problem. Plugging it straight into the wall or a regular power board leaves your devices susceptible to damage.